# Where does the SVG map coordinate start in Adobe illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I know that when I export to SVG, the SVG will have it's own coordinate system.

In illustrator where does (0,0) start?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the origin where you prefer.

Make sure rulers are turned on (ctrl+r/cmd+r). Drag from the upper left corner and choose your new origin.

[image] [image][image]

The origin has changed, but I am not sure how it affects an exported SVG file.